# Print the ID of a YouTube channel using YouTube Data API with Python

Tags: python, youtube-data-api

I want to print the ID of a YouTube channel using the YouTube Data API, but I don't know how.

If I try this:

```
request = youtube.channels().list(
        part='statistics',
        forUsername='TheYTChannel'
    )

response = request.execute()
print(response)
```

it responds with all statistics of the YouTube channel, but I only want the ID of that channel.

How do I print out only the ID of that channel?

Comment: what format does the response come back in?  Do you have an example of the response?

Answer (score 2):

According to the official docs of the [`Channels.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) API endpoint, invoking it with the request parameter [`forUsername`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#forUsername), will produce a [JSON response text](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#response) that includes an object representing the [channel resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#resource-representation) that is associated to the specified user name (if any such channel exists):

```json
{
  "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
  "etag": etag,
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "prevPageToken": string,
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": integer,
    "resultsPerPage": integer
  },
  "items": [
    channel Resource
  ]
}
```

The ID of the channel in question is to be found as the value of the property:

> [**`id`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#id) (string)
> The ID that YouTube uses to uniquely identify the channel.

From your perspective (as user of the [Google's APIs Client Library for Python](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/)), the code would look like:

```py
def find_channel_id_by_username(youtube, user_name):
    request = youtube.channels().list(
        forUsername = user_name,
        fields = 'items/id',
        part = 'id'
    )
    response = request.execute()

    resource = response.get('items')
    if resource:
        return resource[0]['id']
    else:
        return None
```

Note that the result of the function `find_channel_id_by_username` above is either a string representing the ID of the channel associated to the given `user_name`, if there is such channel. In case there's no channel associated with the given `user_name`, the function returns `None`.

Running `find_channel_id_by_username` with `user_name = 'Youtube'` returns back the channel ID `UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ`. When running the function with `user_name = 'TheYTChannel'` it returns `None`.

Also note that above I used the [`fields`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#fields) parameter; that's a good practice: ask from the API only the info that is of actual use.